# How to insert into a table in hibernate using rest api and on that table 2 column are foreign key of another table?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, nhibernate-mapping, dao

I have 3 POJO class `Emp`, `Dep` and `Desig` of three table. I want to insert into `Emp` table columns `e_code`, `e_name`, `dep_id` (foreign key of `Dep` table), `desig_id` (foreign key of `Desig` table), `salary` in hibernate using REST API

My `Emprepositary` class is

```
public class EmpRepositary {

    public void addEmployee(Emp e1) {
        Session session = SessionUtill.getSession();        
        Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
        addEmployee1(session,e1);       
        tx.commit();
        session.close();

    }

    public void addEmployee1(Session session, Emp e1) {
        Emp emp= new Emp();
        emp.setE_code(e1.getE_code());
        emp.setE_name(e1.getE_name());
        emp.setSalary(e1.getSalary());
        emp.setDep(e1.getDep());
        emp.setDesig(e1.getDesig());
        session.save(emp);
    }
}
```

Here is my `Emp` POJO class

```
@Entity
public class Emp {
    @Id
    private int e_code;
    private String e_name;
    private int salary;
    @ManyToOne
    private Dep dep;
    @ManyToOne
    private Desig desig;
    getter setter
    ...
}
```

When I put data in REST API the code run perfectly but data come into database only `e_code`, `e_name`, `salary` but `dept_id`, `desig_id` are `null`, no value come into database...

So my problem is: how to get the data of `dept_id`, `desig_id` into `Emp` table?

Answer (score 0):

Update your Entity like this, hope it works:

```
        @Entity
        public class Emp {

            @Id
            private int e_code;
            private String e_name;
            private int salary;

            @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, optional = false)
            @JoinColumn(name = "dep_id ", nullable = false)
            private Dep dep;

            @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, optional = false)
            @JoinColumn(name = "desig_id ", nullable = false)
            private Desig desig;
            getter setter
            ...
        }
```

Comment: ```@ManyToOne``` has a default fetch type - Eager